# VSTS webtest thinktime in milliseconds

Tags: c#, visual-studio, performance-testing, load-testing

In visual studio VSTS webtest, is there any option to set think time in milliseconds? i tried developing coded web test. what i can set in PreRequestEventArgs is

```
e.Request.ThinkTime = 1;
```

where ThinkTime is int type. So i am unable to set in milliseconds. So as a workaround i am using

```
 public static PreRequestEventArgs ApplyGeneralRequestSettings(PreRequestEventArgs e)
 {
   // e.Request.ThinkTime = 1; 
   // Required 0.5
    Thread.Sleep(500);
 }
```

Are there any better options?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you cannot specify a think time smaller than one second.

Think times are specified in seconds, not in fractions of a second. This makes sense because think times are intended to model how people interact with a web site. The think time corresponds to the time a person takes to read the web page, to think about their response, to type in any data, and finally to click the "Next" button (or do whatever the *do-the-next-thing* action is).

Visual Studio can be set to randomly vary think times during a load test. I have not (yet) determined whether these variations result in an integer number of seconds or whether the result can yield fractions of a second.

It is tempting to use one of the many `delay` or `sleep` methods available. I advise against this because that stops a thread from running and a thread may be used for many virtual users. In experiments I have used `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(...)` and the thread will pause, but other virtual users also pause. In another experiment on a 4-core computer Visual Studio used 4 threads for the virtual users. Each thread ran many virtual users.